# macOS X Mojave 10.14 Beta FTDI USB Serial Driver

Tags: arduino, driver, ftdi, macos-mojave

I just installed macOS Mojave 10.14 Beta and when i connect an Arduino to the USB port, nothing appears in my Arduino IDE ports list.

if i try `ls /dev/tty.*` i just see `/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port` connected. 
On macOS 10.13 everything was working ok. 
I tried reinstalling the driver ( http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP/MacOSX/FTDIUSBSerialDriver_v2_4_2.dmg ) many times, I also tried following https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac but the port never appear.
Suggestions?

Comment: It's one of the problems of upgrading your system too early on Apple. You will just have to wait for a few days for the device drivers to be fixed. I remember my printer not working when I upgraded to High Sierra. It started working a few days later. The best thing to do is to report this to Apple support. There are other people who are also reporting this bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731843/arduino-ide-in-macos-mojave#50731843

Comment: Thank you. I had to install the Beta because I develop apps for iOS.
I also tried to write to ftdichip support.

Comment: @voidbrain were you able to solve this?

Comment: No. Not yet. They suggested me to disable the driver signature but I did not try.

Comment: MacOS beta 3 (8A326h) solved the problem. The port is available again.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up. After the Mojave public release, devices show up and software and connect to the COM ports and seems to send and receive data, but I think not all parts of the communication are working fully. I have a device that is sending data back from a request, but I think it's not seeing changes in RTS / CTS / DTR properly.

Comment: Serial port appeared using a hub (AmazonBasics USB 2.0 4-Port Ultra Mini Hub; Bus-powered) between the USB-C and ESB32 Dev Module. I'm using a 2017 Mac Pro with Mojave version 10.14.1. This mod causes SLAB_USBtoUART to become available and Arduino is able to program the device. I had already installed the above drivers but this was a necessary additional step. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I am having similar problems, with Mojave 10.14.4 and 10.14.5. The first time I reboot after installing the driver, I can see the serial port associated with my EntTec DMX USB Pro Mk2, but then if I unplug it, the port disappears and won’t come back. Does anyone know if FTDI is woking on an updated driver?

Answer (score 4):

Solved for me updating the driver (Use the one below):

Mac OS X 10.9 and above
This driver is signed by Apple

https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm