# Serial Port Error on Energia for MSP430(on Mac)

Tags: macos, msp430

I'm a beginner at coding on the MSP430 and I am a Mac user. Since TI hasnt made launchpad for mac I am trying to use Energia. When I try to run the basic "Blink" program it says " Energia: 1.8.7E21 (Mac OS X), Board: "MSP-EXP430F5529LP"

> Sketch uses 1146 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 48128
>   bytes. Global variables use 28 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving
>   8164 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes. DSLite version
>   8.2.0.1400 Configuring Debugger (may take a few minutes on first launch)...   Initializing Register Database...   Initializing: MSP430
>   error: MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found
>   Failed: MSP430: Error initializing emulator: No USB FET was found
>
> the selected serial port   does not exist or your board is not
>   connected

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried all the available ports that it has given me under `tools>Port:` but none of them seem to work.

Comment: No idea if it’s anything like the FTDI stuff with Arduino, but if so, this may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529131/2836621

Comment: If you want to see if a device special file is created for your device, unplug it and run `ls -l /dev > before.txt`. Then plug it in and wait 5seconds and run `ls -l /dev > after.txt` Then run `opendiff before.txt after.txt` to see what was created.

Comment: Any luck with this?